# iOS CVPixelBufferCreate leaking memory in swift 2

Tags: swift2, avfoundation, avassetwriter, cvpixelbuffer

I'm trying to convert an image into a video, and the right way seems to use a AVAssetWriter with a AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, and it works well, but it leaks memory.

When I convert the CGImage to a CVPixelBuffer, I call CVPixelBufferCreate, which never frees it's memory.

```
func CGImageToPixelBuffer(image: CGImageRef, frameSize: CGSize) -> CVPixelBuffer {

    // stupid CFDictionary stuff
    let keys: [CFStringRef] = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey]
    let values: [CFTypeRef] = [kCFBooleanTrue, kCFBooleanTrue]
    let keysPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>.alloc(1)
    let valuesPointer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>.alloc(1)
    keysPointer.initialize(keys)
    valuesPointer.initialize(values)
    let options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keysPointer, valuesPointer, keys.count,
        UnsafePointer<CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks>(), UnsafePointer<CFDictionaryValueCallBacks>())

    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.alloc(1)

    // here's the leak >:[
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(frameSize.width), Int(frameSize.height),
        kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options, buffer)

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer.memory!, 0);
    let bufferData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer.memory!);

    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bufferData, Int(frameSize.width),
        Int(frameSize.height), 8, 4*Int(frameSize.width), rgbColorSpace,
        CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,
        CGFloat(CGImageGetWidth(image)),
        CGFloat(CGImageGetHeight(image))), image);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer.memory!, 0);
    return buffer.memory!
}
```

And here's the code which calls CGImageToPixelBuffer

```
func saveImageAsVideoFile(path: NSURL, image: UIImage, duration: Double) {
    let writer = try! AVAssetWriter(URL: path, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)

    let videoSettings: NSDictionary = [
        AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(integer: Int(image.size.width)),
        AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(integer: Int(image.size.height))
    ]
    let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings as? [String : AnyObject])
    let inputAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: input, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)
    input.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false
    writer.addInput(input)
    writer.startWriting()
    writer.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)

    // leak starts here
    let buffer = CGImageToPixelBuffer(image.CGImage!, frameSize: image.size)

    // append 30 frames to AVAssetWriter thing
    for i in 0..<30
        if input.readyForMoreMediaData {
            inputAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(buffer, withPresentationTime: CMTimeMake(i, 30))
        }
    }

    //CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer) ??

    input.markAsFinished()
    writer.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
        print("yay")
    })
}
```

CVPixelBufferRelease is not available in swift 2

CVPixelBufferCreate doesn't return a unmanaged pointer in swift 2, so I can't use this [guys code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611086/cvpixelbufferpool-error-kcvreturninvalidargument-6661)

I've tried manually calling destroy and dealloc on the unsafepointer, to no avail.

every time it's called it increases the memory usage, and will crash the device if called enough
[image: memory profile]

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.alloc(1)` isn't balanced by a `dealloc`, however adding that doesn't seem to fix the leak. 
Simply using a `CVPixelBuffer?` does though, and seems simpler:

```
var buffer: CVPixelBuffer?

// TODO: handle status != noErr
let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(frameSize.width), Int(frameSize.height),
    kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options, &buffer)

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer!, 0);
let bufferData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer!);

let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bufferData, Int(frameSize.width),
    Int(frameSize.height), 8, 4*Int(frameSize.width), rgbColorSpace,
    CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0,
    CGFloat(CGImageGetWidth(image)),
    CGFloat(CGImageGetHeight(image))), image);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer!, 0);
```

You should also handle `status != noErr` and unwrap the optional buffer sooner, to avoid all those `buffer!`s.

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar leak. I am not sure but I think the following can be used:

```
let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.alloc(1)
...
let pixelBuffer = bufferPointer.memory!
bufferPointer.destroy()
return pixelBuffer
```